# bluetooth A2DP not playing through USB audio but mplayer is

Tags: audio, raspbian-jessie

I'm amongst a maelstrom of audio mess in Jessie trying to get my USB sound card to work playing audio coming in over A2DP.

I have tried to narrow my problem down to a simple question.

Why does A2DP not work, but `mplayer test.mp3` correctly plays over my USB soundcard?

I have the USB card as my default device, as set in the boot config.

Background info

- I have clean installed Jessie so it's not anything I have done beyond the boot config device priority setting.
- I have had A2DP working, playing out through HDMI and internal 3.5mm
- I'm trying to receive bluetooth audio over A2DP as seen [here](https://github.com/BaReinhard/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install)
- I have raised an issue [here](https://github.com/BaReinhard/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install/issues/49) - With verbose troubleshooting
- I have actually gotten 10 seconds of bluetooth streaming audio. I managed to grab some logs, which I have added below. Now I think bluetooth is actually crashing.

  - As to the cause of the crash, I wonder if my external card (Audio Kontrol 1) is having buffer problems. Because I have had the internal sound card streaming on the RPI3 B bluetooth hardware. Only, that conflicts with the fact mplayer works just fine out the USB card.

Edit: Here's some logs! (sorry I'm a bit of a noob). This is me disconnecting BT on my phone, reconnecting and getting 10sec of audio through my USB sound card.

I just can't understand though why this dies, yet mplayer happily plays audio.

```
Sep 12 10:15:38 greypi logger: [bluez-udev] Bluetooth device is being removed [A0:10:81:5A:23:6B] - MF
Sep 12 10:15:47 greypi kernel: [  283.059769] input: A0:10:81:5A:23:6B as /devices/virtual/input/input2
Sep 12 10:15:47 greypi logger: Action: add
Sep 12 10:15:47 greypi logger: [bluez-udev] Bluetooth device is being added [A0:10:81:5A:23:6B] - MF
Sep 12 10:15:47 greypi logger: [bluez-udev] Patching bluez_source.A0_10_81_5A_23_6B into ALSA sink #0
Sep 12 10:15:49 greypi logger: [bluez-udev] PulseAudio module-loopback returned handle [16]
Sep 12 10:15:49 greypi logger: MF
Sep 12 10:15:58 greypi Getting dbus interface for device: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A0_10_81_5A_23_6B/fd1 interface: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties property_name: org.bluez.MediaTransport1
Sep 12 10:15:58 greypi Detected volume change: 127 (100.00)
Sep 12 10:15:58 greypi Running cmd: amixer cset numid=3 100.00%
Sep 12 10:15:59 greypi Getting dbus interface for device: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A0_10_81_5A_23_6B/fd1 interface: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties property_name: org.bluez.MediaTransport1
Sep 12 10:15:59 greypi Detected volume change: 127 (100.00)
Sep 12 10:15:59 greypi Running cmd: amixer cset numid=3 100.00%
Sep 12 10:16:04 greypi Getting dbus interface for device: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A0_10_81_5A_23_6B/fd1 interface: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties property_name: org.bluez.MediaTransport1
Sep 12 10:16:04 greypi Detected volume change: 127 (100.00)
Sep 12 10:16:04 greypi Running cmd: amixer cset numid=3 100.00%
```

And some kernel logs

```
Sep 12 10:37:54 greypi kernel: [ 1610.078710] input: A0:10:81:5A:23:6B as /devices/virtual/input/input7
Sep 12 10:38:56 greypi kernel: [ 1672.133530] input: A0:10:81:5A:23:6B as /devices/virtual/input/input8
Sep 12 10:39:20 greypi kernel: [ 1696.115859] input: A0:10:81:5A:23:6B as /devices/virtual/input/input9
Sep 12 10:39:20 greypi kernel: [ 1696.171471] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
Sep 12 10:39:20 greypi kernel: [ 1696.181209] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
Sep 12 10:39:20 greypi kernel: [ 1696.181223] Bluetooth: hci0 ACL packet for unknown connection handle 594
Sep 12 10:39:20 greypi kernel: [ 1696.181325] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
Sep 12 10:39:20 greypi kernel: [ 1696.181383] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that this is an audio file format problem : aplay doesn't play compressed formats as of today. For that reason you will most likely want to convert the mp3 to a wav file and then play. One solution is to use sox :

```
sox test.mp3 test.wav
aplay test.wav
```

If it is a device selection problem, then ...
You can choose which device aplay will use to perform playback. First however you need to work out what the device names/numbers are as far as ALSA is concerned.

If you use aplay -l to list the devices, you will see various cards listed, one being your USB device. If your USB device is hw:1, then try to use aplay like so :
aplay -Dhw:1 fileName.mp3

Comment: Updated with logs. I think this is currently a bluetooth problem. Whereas before my example was alluding to a USB problem. Thank you for your time so far... any ideas in light of the new info?